# Closing colorbox after AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, colorbox

I have the following problem. I open a colorbox with an external script in it.

I edit a field in the script opened and press a buton which saves the input in the database.
This is done with AJAX. After AJAX returns successfull I write some content to the main webpage and want to close the colorbox. But the last thing will not happen.

This is my script

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",  
            url: "./editfield_AJAX.php",
            data: {"q_table": q_table, "q_field": q_field, "q_idfield": q_idfield, "q_id": q_id, "waarde":$waarde},
            dataType: "text",
            success:function(data){

                window.parent.$("#" + q_table+q_field).html(data);

                //location.reload(true);
                // Reload the parent and close Cbox
                window.parent.$.colorbox.close();


        }
    });
```

Only when I disable the location.reload(true) command the colorbox closes. But That's not what I want because then the parent will be reloaded.

I have read a lot of solutions here but I can't figure out why it is not working.

Hope someone can help me out.

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an `onClosed` event handler to the colorbox init code and moving the `location.reload(true);` call there:

```
$('selector').colorbox({
    onClosed: function() {
        location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

This way you call `$.colorbox.close();` on ajax success and the reload should be initiated only after the colorbox has closed.

Comment: mm, strange, I did not get any notification of your post.. So sorry of the late reaction. But I don't like to refresh the parent page after closing the colorbox... Is there another option?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand clearly what you are trying to achieve. But since the colorbox is loaded inside the parent's DOM it will get destroyed once the reload is initialized. So it really doesn't matter where you call the `location.reload`.

Comment: One question. From what I could deduct (since you used `window.parent` to access the colorbox plugin), your colorbox's Content Type is `iframe: true`. Am i correct?